# Own function using getchar() slower than scanf

Tags: c, optimization, input, scanf, getchar

So, I know scanf isn't the fastest way to read input from stdin, and talking to my teacher other day he said that a simple getchar() function till '\n', to read a line, would be a lot faster than scanf with all its security concerns.
So I came up with the following function:

```
int read(char *s) {
    char tmp = 1;
    unsigned short i;
    for (i=0; tmp!='\n'&&tmp!=EOF; i++) {
        tmp = getchar();
        s[i] = tmp;
    }
    if (tmp==EOF)
        return -1;
    return i-1;
}
```

It reads a string till '\n' or EOF is found, as you can see. If EOF is found it returns -1, if it reads correctly till a new line it returns the lenght of the string. Using this function I removed the scanf("%s", s) and also the strlen(s) that I was using to know the lenght of the string read, since now using only the read function I already have this information. The thing is that, after submiting my new solution to the online judge, the running time of my code went from 0.16s to 0.18s.
Shouldn't it had been faster? Or did I screw up with my read function?

By the way, the problem that I applied this solution to is this: 
http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_1251_en.html

Comment: With regards to speed: are you sure you are measuring the actual IO time and not mostly other things like startup time? By the way: I don't think your EOF handling works: getchar return value should be int because EOF is negative. There's also a buffer overflow if input line is longer than s.

Comment: What your teacher probably meant was that you could skip handling the string totally: just read a char at a time and make a note of the frequencies of the letters as you go. E.g. your read() function could have as argument a pointer to an array that contains number of occurrences per character (and read() will fill that array). Then later your code just needs to traverse the array once and print the number of occurrences and char code.

Comment: I know about the max lenght of any input so my code handles it. My teacher talked about this in general, I just applied to this problem arbitrarily. Actually it does work, a char can receive the EOF value.

Comment: I know this is ancillary, but you mention security issues with `scanf`, and you are correct... yet you read into a buffer of unknown size until the input ends.  That's exactly as insecure as `scanf`.  Prefer `fgets`.

Comment: @LuanCristianThums yeah, I should have been more clear: char may work on your machine (and probably will) but this is not guaranteed. One of the 'features' of C is that char is not guaranteed to be signed or unsigned. If you are using gcc you can test what could go wrong with "-funsigned-char".

Comment: @jku ah, yeah, forgot about unsigned chars. But that kind of (just kind of) doesn't matter because I know what compiler the online judge uses and chars can assume negative values there. The real question is, shouldn't it be faster than scanf? One thing I've thought is that the runtime showed on the judge may not be that realiable because there are lot of programs running on that machine and every submission may have a different processing power depending on what is running in the backgroud (I think).

Comment: @EdS. I don't know if I was clear, I understand that scanf is slower because it concerns about a lot of possible security problems. Regarding security, my question was about why this function wasn't faster than scanf (I expected it to be). As it was the solution to a online judge problem I know how the data will be arranged and know that all the strings will have 1000 characters or less and end if '\n'.

Comment: @Luan Cristian Thums Note: "a char can receive the EOF value" is at best misguided and is _not_ the issue.  `getchar()` does _not_ return a `char`, it returns an `int`.  The function works like `fgetc()` which "... obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` ... " or EOF. So of the 256 different characters, you will get values 0 to 255 and EOF will be some negative number.  If you assign this 1 of 257 different results to a `char`, the EOF in the `char` will be indistinguishable from one of the `char`.  Use an `int` to receive `getchar()`. It's much better programming.

Comment: Programming bugs aside, there is not enough information to provide a definitive answer to your question. The problem may be that `scanf()` was compiled with optimizations, while your code has not. The problem may be that `scanf()` is able to better leverage internal knowledge of internal I/O data structures that your routine does not. The problem may have to do with the programming problems in your code both within this routine and outside of this routine. Try benchmarking this routine against `scanf()`, and show your results.

Comment: The only "security" concern I can think you would be referring to would be buffer overruns. Unfortunately your proposed code doesn't actually fix that :-)